# Accept an interface, pass the result to a channel with a corresponding data type

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I'm running a WebSocket which processes different type of data.
I want to stick to the **DRY** (don't repeat yourself) principle and use one single WS function which does all the same WS stuff (connect, hearthbeat, accept WS messages, etc...), but to store the data in different, corresponding data type.

In brief, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
type wsItemHolder interface {
    ProcessItemData(data []byte) // data = WS JSON msg
}

type MyCustomType map[string]int


func (data MyCustomType) ProcessItemData(data []byte) {
    // process my MyCustomType stuff by updating data by reference (as it's a map)
}

func processWebsocketData(data wsItemHolder, myChan chan <- ChanDataType) {
    for {
        // Do the basic WS stuff
        data.processItem()
        // pass the updated data to a channel
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

I can't pass `myChan` to `processWebsocketData`, because:

1. If I define it as  `chan <- wsItemHolder`, when I receive the data on the other channel end, it's already an interface, not a `MyCustomType` and I can view it but I can't process it - iterate, access fields, etc... as it's not a map.
2. If I define the channel as `chan <- MyCustomType`, the `processWebsocketData` must be defined as it accepts this particular type of channel and I can't use it for other data types. So all the code reuse benefit is gone.

**Why I don't want to use locks instead of channels:**

My main goroutine looks like this:

```
func Main() {
    go processWebsocketData(wsItemHolder) // Start independent WS connection to process data type 1
    for {
        a := getAndDoSomethingWithTheLastData()
    }
}
```

So while I am reading and processing the data from the WS in the main goroutine, I would block the writing in the WS goroutine and cause bottlenecks.

How can I do this with channels?
If impossible, what are the alternatives?

So far I have looked into https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map but I'm not sure how/if it solves the lock problem.

Comment: The problem is due to the underlying design. You're trying to get two things at the same time which are incompatible: you want to  be able to pass any of a set of types to the channel, and you want the thing processing the channel to treat the values as one specific type. Once you fix that design conflict, the problem disappears.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for your input. I'm coming from a dynamically typed language and so far I'm struggling to reuse code exactly due to Go's static data types limitations. Do you have any suggestion for alternative design so that I can still use one function for the WebSocket? As the processing of the WS message happens inside the WS loop, which happens in the WS function, I have no idea how in other way would I construct my WS function.

Comment: to rephrase Adrian comment, use an empty `interface{}` type to convey the fact that the channel can accept many kind of values. In the channel consumer, type assert the output data to figure out what is the type of structure you are dealing with.